# Bootstrap grid system overlap when stacked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to a create basic 4-square using the Bootstrap grid system. When the screen is medium and large, I want it to be a four square, filling up the page and when the screen is small, the 4-square get stacked.

I thought that I got it working but when the screen size gets small, the 2nd and the 3rd box overlap. Any advice on what I did wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
         html, body, .container {
            height: 100%;
        }

        html {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        .divGeneral{
            text-align: center;
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        .row{
            height: 50%
        }

        #topL{
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        #topR{
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        #botL{
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        #botR{
            min-height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="topL">trend charts

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="topR">detail
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="botL">refire
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="botR">ncr
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The min-height is causing the overlap. But I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want; not well enough to answer anyway.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want 2 rows 2 columns when on 'normal' screens and 1 row 4 columns in small screens, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following min-height and height :

```
    html {
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    .row{
        height: 50%
    }

    #topL{
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    #topR{
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    #botL{
        min-height: 100%;
    }
    #botR{
        min-height: 100%;
    }
```

And try something like that :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="topL">trend charts
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="topR">detail
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="botL">refire
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 divGeneral" id="botR">ncr
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT : See comments

Comment: It's possible the two pixel border is causing issues, too. BS3 grid is very precise.

Comment: I think the issue come from the forced height : 50% of the row.

Comment: why "col-xs-12" it resize automatically to 100% if the media qeury is reached

Comment: I know this is an old post but I've been having the same problem recently.
The issue was that I had forced a height on a div. Removing fixed the problem straight away! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 divGeneral" id="topL">trend charts

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 divGeneral" id="topR">detail
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 divGeneral" id="botL">refire
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 divGeneral" id="botR">ncr
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Will that not result in a 2x2 regardless of the screen ? BS3 is mobile first.